# In Angularjs, how to update table data after deleting a row from it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using the angularjs to call Asp.net Web API. After I delete a row from the table?

I also did not find the solution in w3schools.

My HTML code

```
 <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter: search">
     <td>{{ user.Id }}</td>
     <td>{{ user.FullName }}</td>
     <td>{{ user.Mobile }}</td>
     <td>{{ user.Birthdate }}</td>
     <td>{{ user.Gender }}</td>
     <td>{{ user.AcademicLevel }}</td>

     <td>
```

My Angularjs code

```
$scope.DeleteUser = function (id) {
    UserID = $scope.users[id].Id;
    $http.delete('/api/users/' + UserID).success(function (data) {
       (function (data) {
        $scope.error = "error " + data;
    });

}
```

I searched in Stackoverflow, I found some of these where they did not work for me, they confused me.

```
$scope.refresh()
$scope.apply();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, handling server requests in your controller is a bad idea. As a rule of thumb, use services to delegate calls to the server, and use the controller for "gluing" up your models to your view.

There are a few issues in your code, it should look something like this:

```
$scope.DeleteUser = function (id) {
    var userId = $scope.users[id].Id;
    $http.delete('/api/users/' + userId)
          .success(function (data) {
             $scope.error = "error " + data;
          });
}
```

Even if the call to the server was successful, you never updated your front-end model. What you have read on other topics regarding $scope.refresh(), I suppose that has the purpose of fetching the data again, like so:

```
$scope.refresh = function(){
    $http.get('/api/users')
          .success(function(data){
               $scope.users = data;
          });
}
```

So in order the refresh your view, you must update your model.

```
$scope.DeleteUser = function (id) {
    var userId = $scope.users[id].Id;
    $http.delete('/api/users/' + userId)
          .success(function (data) {
             //either this
             $scope.refresh();
             //or this
             $scope.users.splice(id,1);
          });
}
```

Comment: Why 1? in splice(id,1);.

Comment: Because the first parameter of splice is the index from where to remove an item, and the second is how many to remove, in your case just one item. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Answer (score 5):

Two solutions : once you've performed your deletion, remove the user from the users array by doing a slice :

```
$scope.DeleteUser = function (index) {
    var UserID = $scope.users[index].Id;
    $http.delete('/api/users/' + UserID).then(function(del) {
        $scope.users.splice(index,1);
    });
}
```

You can get the index of the user by using $index in your ng-repeat but as your code may be asynchronous this is not recommended.

Or, you can just make another get from your API once your deletion is resolved.

```
$scope.DeleteUser = function (index) {
    var UserID = $scope.users[index].Id;
    $http.delete('/api/users/' + UserID).then(function(del) {
        $http.get('/api/users').then(function(data){
            $scope.users = data;
        });
    });
}
```

But... What if the person who's using your application is deleting users faster than your API is able to ?

First solution will fail for sure, and the second will hardly maintain you DOM clean as long as all requests came back in the same order they were sent.
One solution is to prevent any request to the API as long as another is already pending.

In JavaScript as *Functions* are in fact *executable Objects* they can have properties. So we'll add a `isBusy` property to the DeleteUser function to know when it is already processing.

```
$scope.DeleteUser = function (index) {
    if(!$scope.DeleteUser.isBusy){
        var UserID = $scope.users[id].Id;
        $scope.DeleteUser.isBusy = true;

        $http.delete('/api/users/' + UserID).then(function(del) {
            $scope.users.splice(id,1);
            $scope.DeleteUser.isBusy = false;
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Update code to use `.then()` on `$http` promise object as `.success()` is now deprecated.

Comment: sorry, indexOfUser is having same value as id. (repetition) that is also confirmed by in this line : UserID = $scope.users[id].Id;

Comment: I have edited my post according to your informations.

Comment: By the way it's not relevant to consider that the index is the ID. Think about it just for a second. If you delete ID 10 which is index 10, id 11 will become index 10. Kind of logical. the safest way is the second one. Avoid using slice in asynchronous application it's a best practice.

Comment: I completely agree for you about that. You are excellent. I experimented that and proved it.

Comment: So you can flag my answer as relevant ;)

Comment: how? because  as answer has already gone before you open this point. The solution was already provided. But let me know how to mark as relevant? Btw, I have less than 15 reputation where I can't point to your answer as 'useful'.

Comment: Not a problem don't worry. ;)

Comment: I like the idea of setting a `busy` flag. Nice answer. I will go with the option of making another API call after deletion instead of removing deleted item from DOM for one reason which is records/items pagination. Doing slice when the data are in pages can only delete a record from current page hence need to repopulate the pages.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the user from the array:

```
// Find index of the user
var index = $scope.users.indexOf(id);
// Remove user from array
$scope.users.splice(index, 1);
```

Also, why are you fetching the user's id, when you already have it?:

```
$scope.DeleteUser = function (id) {
    $http.delete('/api/users/' + id).success(function (data) {
        var index = $scope.users.indexOf(id);
        $scope.users.splice(index, 1);
    });
}
```

Comment: not $scope.users.indexOf(id) because collection of user, on id's. use underscore of make js function to find user, like: var userToDelete = _.find($scope.users, function(user) { return user.id == id}); and after $scope.users.splice($scope.users.indexOf(userToDelete ), 1);

Comment: Why 1? in splice(id,1);.

Comment: It is a method to remove **one** item from a javascript array